# Allowing use of certain characters in input form using angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms, validation

I am creating a log in form for my project and have been adding validation on the form. Because it is a custom username I want to allow the use of unique characters on a username such as an ampersand. Is there a built in way to allow the use of unique characters in angular or is there need for creating a custom filter?

Answer (score 0):

I would check out [ngPattern](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngPattern). It seems like you can use a regex to allow for special characters:

```
  angular.module('ngPatternExample', [])
    .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
      $scope.regex = '\\d+';
    }]);
```